# How to add customized tags quickly in Sublime text 2?

Tags: html, css, tags, sublimetext2

Sorry for the newbie question. I'm using multiple times of the same tag with the same class, for example:

`<p class = "paragraph_1"></p>`

I'm just wondering how to add this same tag quickly in Sublime Text 2? I know the default tags can be added quickly by just typing a part of them and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Is there any similar convenient way for those tags customized by myself?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sublime Text HTML package inserts snippets into the completion system. If you also want to have your tags, you can just write a snippet for each tag.

To create a snippet:

1. Open your User directory

   1. Click on `Preferences`
   2. then on `Browse Packages...`
   3. Open the directory `User`
2. Create a file `snippet_name.sublime-snippet`
3. Paste this into your snippet and change the content as you want:

```xml
<snippet>
  <!-- Example: Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}. -->
  <content><![CDATA[
<p class="paragraph_1">$0</p>
]]></content>
  <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
  <tabTrigger>par1</tabTrigger>
  <description>Tag</description>
  <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
  <scope>text.html.basic</scope>
</snippet>
```

However using [SnippetMaker](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SnippetMaker) you can easily shorten the process. Just select the content, press `ctrl+shift+p` and write `SnippetMaker: Make Snippet`.

Additional remarks:

- You can remove the snippet by removing the file.
- The position of `$0` marks cursor position at the end of the snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the instruction :) If I have many tags that I want to repeat in my code and I'll only use each of them for several times, I guess setting up the configurations for all of them might cost even more time than just typing them out. However, I think this method is extremely useful if I have only a small number of customized tags, which are used huge amount of times. 

What I'm thinking is that, would it be possible that I could let Sublime text editor recognize those already existing customized tags automatically so that I can use them with just typing out snippets?

Comment: Yes that would be possible, but you would have to write or search for plugin which has the behavior.
However you could search for other plugin, which help with writing html. [Emmet](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet) seems to be very popular and helpful, the actions are documented [here](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/). This is not exactly what you requested, but still might be a solution.